# Downloads section in Gitlab repo

Tags: gitlab

I was a heavy Bitbucket user for a long time but moved to GitLab due the advanced great features that GL has.

But there is a amazing Bitbucket feature that I can't found in GitLab... the "Download" section. Basically in Bitbucket you can upload a file that you don't want to keep track in the repo, like a pdf, a document or whatever you want to keep related to the project that you are working.

There is anything similar for Gitlab that I didn't realize that exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't supported by GitLab: "artifacts" uploads and storage are more in GitLab CI territory, and are discussed in "[Allow access to build artifacts of GitLab CI](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4522830-allow-access-to-build-artifacts-of-gitlab-ci)".

Although recently you could [upload any filtetpye to the wiki of a project](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/6488530-allow-upload-any-filetype-to-the-wiki). That could serve as a workaround for this Bitbucket feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your code on GL, but steel use the Download on BB, isn't it?